# Stanford NER - where is the chinese classifier "chinese.misc.diststim.crf.ser.gz"

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use the Stanford NER to do Chinese Entity Recognition in nltk, but was unable to locate the classifier. Would anyone know where this is?

The model is provided on the website, but not the classifier.

Found a copy of the classifiers here:

http://blog.csdn.net/shijiebei2009/article/details/42525091

but it does not work on ntlk,

and gives the following error:

Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier

Answer (score -1):

```
java -mx1000m -cp stanford-ner.jar;stanford-chinese-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar;lib/* edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile %1
```